# VBA Excel Macro .copy destination Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

i hope someone can help me.

I tried everything, but i cant fix the following code:

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A2:J2" & Range("A2:J2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count - 3).Range("A2")
```

If i leave the destination line and use the following code instead, it works.

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A2:J2" & Range("A2:J2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy '_
    'Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count - 3).Range("A2")

Sheets("All Docs " & Date).Select '(All Docs " & Date) = (Sheets.count-3)
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Any suggestions? Thx a lot.

Comment: What happens when you try to use the first code? Is there an error given, or does it just not copy?  Also, make sure that your `.End(xlDown).Row` isn't shooting down to the last row in Excel, which could cause an issue as well most likely.

Comment: Do you have more than 3 sheets?

Comment: I don't follow your range definition. "A2:J2" & Range("A2:J2").End(xlDown).Row  That would lead to a range like "A2:J2##"  You might need to take out the 2 in J2.

Comment: Hi Thx for the Answers. @BruceWayne error 1004 appears. i think there isnt a problem with the .end(xldown).row, because i use the second code i posted, it works fine.

Comment: @user3964075 yes, i have more than 3 sheets... around 30. And there will be every month 4 more... thats why i use sheets(sheets.count)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's happening.  You're trying to get a "block" of data, from A2:J2 across, and then to some row going down, say A10:J10 - to end up with a range `A2:J10` that you want to copy.

What I think might be happening is there is no data (or perhaps not enough) under your Row 2, so Excel's getting your `.End(xlDown.Row` as `1048576`.

Try using this:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Long
With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    lastRow = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 10)).End(xlDown).Row

    If lastRow >= 1048576 Then
        lastRow = 2
    Else
        lastRow = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 10)).End(xlDown).Row
    End If

    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 10)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count - 3).Range("A2")

End With

End Sub
```

Note about using `Sheets(Sheets.Count)`.  This is *not* the same as using say, `Sheets("LastSheet")`.  If you change the order of your worksheets around, this will affect where your data is pasted into.  I.E. if your right most sheet has your data (which I think it does, since you're using it to get the info to paste), and you move it anywhere else but the end of the file, then your data won't properly be found.  `Sheets.Count` refers to the very last (right most) sheet.  And `Sheets.Count - 3` refers to the sheet three over from the end (again, moving *that* sheet will also result in not pasting where you want).

Comment: thx for the answer, actually there are enough rows. about 130... sometimes more, sometimes less. From my point of view the failure has to be in the Destination:= line, because without this it works fine.

Comment: also thx for the hint, with the sheets(sheet.count) thing. But its correct. My last 3 sheets are allways the data sheets. And then there are every month 4 sheets added before the last 3 sheets.

Comment: I recommend walking through the macro, one step at a time, by pressing `F8` when in VBA.  You should then be able to follow how the ranges are being set (you can hover the mouse over variable names, and their value will appear).  That will help you with where the error is going.  See if that helps when you use `Destination`. Let us know what you find!  (The above code works for me, so I'm curious if it's an issue with the Sheet layout, not necessarily that you're trying to use `Destination`).